# How to detect fraud sites: eg, https://www.americanexpress.com vs. https://www262.americanexpress.com

Tags: security

Is the www262 prefix a dead giveaway of a fake Amex site?

https://www262.americanexpress.com/eaol/welcome.do

Note that

https://www262.americanexpress.com

by itself redirects to

https://www.americanexpress.com

but once at the legit site, if you add "eaol/welcome.do" to the url as shown below

https://www.americanexpress.com/eaol/welcome.do

it becomes an invalid URL.

I believe that there are settings (in web server config?) to configure additional urls to map/redirect to the same website, but is something else, like fraud, going on here?

To make a long story short, I received suspicious phone calls and snail mail phishing, so I looked up a telephone number on a letter I received from "Amex" and found the following site that looked legit except for this one page:

https://www.frugaltravelguy.com/2012/05/credit-card-company-contact-information.html

This contained the telephone number that was on the suspicious letter I received and linked to the www262 amex URL above.

In technical terms, is the www262 URL performing some sort of redirect to fool unsuspecting visitors into think this URL is real?

Additional point:

Note that on the Frugalw ebsite the link that they posted to the Bank of America site began with "**www5**.bankofamerica.com: instead of the plain "www."

Comment: Looking at the certificate of www262. I can see that the owner is `American Express Travel Related Services Company, Inc.` and verified by `Verizon Enterprise Solutions`. Also note that it is an EV. which requires more rigorous verification than the standard one. Also 'www' or 'www262' or 'www5' are just subdomains. They do not tell anything about a sites trust worthiness. Always check the certificates

Comment: Your AmEx link appears to be at the company (not redirected), but is not a functioning link.  https://www.frugaltravelguy.com is not affiliated with AmEx.

Comment: The fact the domain is americanexpress.com means that it's not possible for it to be a fraudulent website.

Comment: "In technical terms, is the www262 URL performing some sort of redirect to fool unsuspecting visitors into think this URL is real?" - To be crystal clear, the link is legitimately invalid and owned by American Express, and it legitimately been configured to redirect you to a valid page.  You cannot phish a user if they are legitimately going to a domain owned by American Express and specifically if it's actually americanexpress.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Truly said, this does not look like a fraud.

AmEx is really the owner of the domain `americanexpress.com`, so it is their
DNS server that redirects `www262.americanexpress.com` to the IP address
of `148.173.96.127`, with any tricks extremely unlikely.

A whois lookup finds the owner as "American Express Travel Related Services Company, Inc." which is a legit company with a
[website](https://travel.americanexpress.com/travel-experts).

While the letter you received may have been a sham,
the details you have given in your post seem correct.